# iPhone: Tell a friend functionality library

Tags: iphone

I am starting implementing Tell A Friend functionality for my iPhone App which allows you to select friends from your contacts list and send them an email/sms etc. It is very common functionality for most of iPhone App so just wondering if someone already have done it and available as library like Sharekit? I have searched but couldn't find.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharekit offers this in a way. You can set it up to share by email. Sharing by SMS is a lot harder, since Apple do not currently provide access to the SMS services through the API, so you would have to use an online service (of which there are many) to route the messages.

Comment: Thanks. Yah I can use this but I ( rather my Manager :) ) want Contacts list before, select multiple contacts, and click Send button to send predefined message. Anyway I can implement this if not already available.